# Getting Error "Call to undefined method Joomla\CMS\Editor\Editor::getContent"

Tags: editor, joomla-4

I am upgrading one of my component to support Joomla 4 and I am getting this error in webpage

> Call to undefined method Joomla\CMS\Editor\Editor::getContent

The code that throws this error is in views->tmpl->edit.php file:

```
var datdescription = <?php echo $this->editor->getContent( 'datdescription' ); ?>
```

When I checked Joomla Site for [backward compatibility](https://docs.joomla.org/Potential_backward_compatibility_issues_in_Joomla_4) I could not find any solution. But when I checked this link https://api.joomla.org/cms-3/deprecated.html and searched for `getContent` I found this:

```
\Joomla\CMS\Editor\Editor::getContent()
```

deprecated Use `Joomla.editors API, see core.js`

Does anyone know how to solve this?

Comment: Are you using the Stub Generator as a tool in upgrading? https://github.com/joomla/joomla-cms/blob/staging/build/stubGenerator.php

Comment: No I am just upgrading by following Joomla docs and backward compatibility docs.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As it is explained in core.js: instead of using **getContent()** method you should use:

> - To get the current editor value:

```
Joomla.editors.instances['jform_articletext'].getValue();
```

Where `jform_articletext` means the textarea id and you have to change that value if your textarea id is something else. So in your case it could be for example:

```
let datdescription = Joomla.editors.instances['datdescription'].getValue();
```